# Trying to showing a dialog on DispatcherUnhandledException

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application into which I'm adding some top level, catch all error handling. I handle the DispatcherUnhandledException event like so:

```
    private void App_OnDispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_isHandlingError)
        {
            _log.Error("Critical unhandled error", e.Exception);
            e.Handled = true;
            return;
        }

        _isHandlingError = true;
        var vm = _windsorContainer.Resolve<ErrorReporterViewModel>();

        Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            vm.Details = FailureMessageBuilder.CreateContent(e.Exception);
            var view = new ErrorReporterView { DataContext = vm };

            view.Show();
        });

        e.Handled = true;

        NotifyOfException(e.Exception, vm.Description);

        _isHandlingError = false;
    }
```

The problem is, that the call to Show() (or ShowDialog) never returns, and the error dialog is never shown.

What might be the issue?

Comment: Have you debugged it?

Comment: Probably not..most people I am noticing don't know how to even use the debugger.. what a travesty ...

Comment: Just to clarify - the event fires, and the handler is called. But the call to Show never returns.

Comment: Simplify your code, comment stuff out and start with var view = new Window(); and verify that works.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have attached your event to the Application?

```
cApp.Dispatcher.UnhandledException += new DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventHandler(Dispatcher_UnhandledException);
                cApp.InitializeComponent();
                cApp.Run(new MainWindow());
```

And then

```
private static void Dispatcher_UnhandledException(object sender, DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
...e.Exception.Message
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify - the event fires, and the handler is called. But the call to Show never returns.